# SIGABRT and thread related exception but works fine during debug

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

The below code blows up during run time but works fine during debug. I cant understand why. I am joining the thread in destructor as required.

Could some one help ?

surprisingly the code works fine during debug.

Tried couple of times in debug and every time seems fine.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<thread>
#include<memory>

using namespace std;

template<typename T> class Runnable
{
    private:
        std::thread t;

        void runImpl()
        {
            static_cast<T*>(this)->run();
        }

    public:
        virtual void run() = 0;
        void start()
        {
            this->t = std::thread(&Runnable::runImpl, this);
        }

        ~Runnable()
        {
            std::cout << "I am in the destructor of the base class" << std::endl;
            if(t.joinable())
            {
                std::cout << "joinable" << std::endl;
                t.join();
            }
            else
                std::cout << "not joinable" << std::endl;
        }
};

class HelloWorld : public Runnable<HelloWorld>
{
    public:
        void run()
        {
            std::cout <<  "I am in thread id = " << std::this_thread::get_id()  << " and the message is : HelloWorld How are you" << std::endl;
        }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::cout << "I am in the main thread id = " << std::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;
    {
        HelloWorld item;
        item.start();
    }
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is there any specific reason why you're using CRTP and not just plain inheritance for your `Runnable` class? Also when implementing a `start` method I would expect an API to also provide a `stop` method. You could also get rid of `start` and could RAII-like start and stop the thread in the constructor/destructor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a race on `*this`, between the worker thread calling a virtual member function, and the main thread entering the destructor. This exhibits undefined behavior.

Practically speaking, the vtable pointer may already have been updated to that of `Runnable`, and the thread ends up calling a pure virtual function.

Comment: Igor Tandetnik , Yes you are right , that is what is going on. I just put some sleep after the start call in main to verify this. seems fine now , i understand atleast what is going on. perfect mate!!!